# How to clear PasswordBox value using MVVM pattern or caliburn micro

Tags: wpf, mvvm, data-binding, caliburn.micro

How should I clear the password box value upon bad input with? I have seen some answers like "Send passwordbox to viewmodel", but that just breaks MVVM pattern. 
 current xaml

```
<PasswordBox x:Name="PasswordInput" Style="{DynamicResource PWbox}" cal:Message.Attach="[Event PasswordChanged] = [Action PasswordChanged($source)]" Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="2"/>
```

viewmodel

```
public void PasswordChanged(PasswordBox source)
        {
            OldPassword = source.Password;
        }

private string _oldPassword;
        public string OldPassword
        {
            get { return _oldPassword; }
            set
            {

                _oldPassword = value;
                NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => OldPassword);
            }
        }
```

Comment: What is the point of using the `PasswordBox` when you are handling the password as plain text? Then consider to user the `TextBox` which allows easier handling. `PasswordBox` is intended to be used with the `PasswordChanged` event and the `SecurePassword` property. Inside this event you extract the value and validate it. If the result is an invalid password, you simply call `PasswordBox.Clear` inside the event handler. Since data binding will leak strings, the `PasswordBox` doesn't support data binding to implement classic MVVM data flow. Note that using event handlers does not break MVVM!

Comment: The PasswordBox control is just itself breaking the MVVM pattern.
The usual way to work with it in MVVM is to create attached dependency properties in a helper class ; thus leading 100% times to expose the password as clear text.
Another way would be to create a usercontrol wrapping the password box, using it the way it was designed to (with code behind event handlers), and expose the userControl a more MVVM-friendly way.

Answer (score 0):

I've found you can trick it by toggling a bound IsEnabled value & using

```
    private void PasswordBox_IsEnabledChanged(object sender, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (sender is PasswordBox passwordBox 
            && e.NewValue is bool newValue
            && !newValue)
        {
            passwordBox.Clear();
        }
    }
```